# Remove duplicate from string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I beginner in php.

I have this code:

```
$string = '["Rumia","Rumia","Joarilla de las Matas","Rumia"]';
```

How can I remove duplicate from this string?

I build this string by this code:

```
$res = app('geocoder')->geocode($request->input('city'))->get();
foreach ($res as $value) {
if($formatter->format($value, '%L') !=""){
$string .= '"'.$formatter->format($value, '%L').'"'. ",";
}
}

if (strlen($string) > 0){
$string = mb_substr($string, 0, -1);
echo "[".$string."]";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_unique($string); //this is for an array,

$new_var = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $string))); //this is for a string
```

Answer (score 0):

This "string" is an array. Then you could use the [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php) function like this:

```
array_unique($string);
```

It will return an array with only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$string = implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $string)));
```